Black Formatter in VS code line break
The black formatter extension for vs code puts '()' around some of my conditions in my code, and also breaks the line where i dont want to.
This is my code before formatting
if self.size - index < index:  # if it is closer to the end, start from the tail

and after formatting it transforms to:
if (
    self.size - index < index
):  # if it is closer to the end, start from the tail

Another example:
if current.prev is not None and current.next is not None:  # if there are elements at the left & right

that transforms to
if (
    current.prev is not None and current.next is not None
):  # if there are elements at the left & right

I don't know if it is because some sort of line width limit or something, but I would like to know if there is something I can do to avoid this behaviour
Maybe I can get rid of black formatter and use default of vs code, but I dont know if it exists or how to configure it

Do you have any additional settings or codes in place? The code in question has not changed with me.  Please see how to ask.
minimal reproducible example
